# Regex to filter out certain characters

Tags: javascript, regex

What would a regex string look like if you were provided a random string such as :

> "u23ntfb23nnfj3mimowmndnwm8"

and I wanted to filter out certain characters such as  2, b, j, d, g, k and 8?

So in this case, the function would return `'2bjd8'`.

There's a lot of literature on the internet but nothing straight to the point. It shouldn't be too hard to create a regex to filter the string right?

ps. this is not homework but I am cool with daft punk

Comment: Which characters, specifically, would you like to include (or, alternatively, exclude)? Is the list provided in the question comprehensive?

Comment: Do you only want one occurence of the given character, or all? Do you need them separated into an array, or should they be concatenated as a string?

Comment: @marcusdei why do you feel that this is a good task for a regular expression? I'm not saying it can't be done, but it's unnecessary, and overcomplicates the code.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to create a regular expression first and then execute it over your `string`.

This is what you need :

```js
var str = "u23ntfb23nnfj3mimowmndnwm8";
var re = /[2bjd8]+/g;
alert((str.match(re) || []).join(''));
```

*To get all the matches use `String.prototype.match()` with your Regex.*

It will give you the following matches in output:

> 2 b2 j d 8

Comment: Thanks a lot, let me run some tests

Comment: Output gives me "2". Sorry for my initial comment, I mis-read the question. I thought the OP wanted to exclude the character set, not include only the character set.

Comment: If he wants an array of all the matches, he should apply `str.match(re)`, maybe joining it with `.join('')` to concatenate all the matches into one string. This is what he expects from his function: He should apply `str.match(re).join('');`

Comment: Yeah `.match()` seems to be the way to go.

Comment: Like it's said it will delete those letters, okay to get all the matches we just need to use `String.prototype.match()`.

Comment: In its current version, you do not match against the entire set, and you print all other characters to console.log, and an array version to the alert box, i.e. `2,b2,j,d,8`. In general, if possible provide output in comment in your code, so its possible to see directly what your code produces, as the question is indeed a little vague as to what it want as output.

Comment: Keep in mind that the OP specified that the input would be a random string and only used that specific string as an example. If the input string doesn't include any of the specified characters then str.match(re) will return null and str.match(re).join('') will throw an error. To avoid that, I'd recommend the following adjustment to account for that possibility:

( str.match(re) || [] ).join('')

Comment: @Spencer Yes, you are right about that, it might throw an exception if it doesn't match, but that's because I just gave a quick solution to show how it should be done, I am editing it, thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You could use a character class to define the characters.

Using the [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method to analyze the string and then filter out the duplicates.

```
function filterbychr(str) {
  var regex = /[28bdgjk]/g
  return str.match(regex).filter(function(m,i,self) {
    return i == self.indexOf(m)
  }).join('')
}

var result = filterbychr('u23ntfb23nnfj3mimowmndnwm8') //=> "2bjd8"
```

Comment: @marcusdei, You're welcome, let me know if you need me to change anything.